# Add models to specific user (Django)

Tags: python, mysql, django

Good evening,
I am working on some little website for fun and want users to be able to add items to their accounts. What I am struggling with is coming up with a proper solution how to implement this properly.

I thought about adding the User Object itself to the item's model via `ForeignKey` but wouldn't it be necessary to filter through all entries in the end to find the elements attached to x user? While this would work, it seems quite inefficient, especially when the database has grown to some point. What would be a better solution?

Comment: as a principle, avoid duplicating information. If you stored the name of the user in the items, it would be very inefficient for a number of reasons. Assuming you use a RDBMS, the *proper* way to relate two entities (i.e. the items and the user) is to use a foreign key (the relationship can be one-to-one, many-to-one, many-to-many, of course)

Comment: I can't see why it's inefficient if you have user as a foreign key in your item model. If you have a `user`, then you could do `Item.objects.filter(user=user)` which is just one query to get all items for that user, right?

Comment: This question sounds more like a database question than a Django question.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your use case, a `User` can have many items and and an `Item` can belong to multiple users. It this s the case, using [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) seems the way to go :

```
class Item(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='items')
```

You can then query items from a specific user like this:

```
    # adding an item to a user
    user.items.add(my_item)

    # query user items
    user.items.all()
    user.items.filter(name__startswith='Hello')
```

If you want to store additional information about the relationship, such as the date were the item was linked to the user, you have to specifiy an explicit intermediate model:

```
    class Item(models.Model):
        users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', through='ItemUser', related_name='users')

    class ItemUser(models.Model):
        """Explicit intermediary model"""
        user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

To create the binding beetween a `User` and an `Item`, just instanciate the intermediate model:

```
    binding = ItemUser(user=user, item=item)
    binding.save()

    assert user in item.users.all()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort already! I am still trying to get my head around how this relationship works. `user.items.add(my_item)`. Is `user` in this case a `User` object? I tried to use `this_user=User.object.get(pk=request.user.id)` to get the `User` objects for the user calling the view. `this_user.items.add(request.POST[key]` breaks the view at this point, although without any error it seems. Did I misunderstand something here?

Comment: Keep in mind that the ORM expects model instances most of the time. So `this_user.items.add(request.POST[key])` should probably be `this_user.items.add(Item.objects.get(pk=request.POST[key]))`.

Comment: That would mean I have to create the Item objects first and then add it via `.items.add()` to the `User` object? In your example model there is the field 'users' which I would have to fill with a User model. Do I have to add a User model to the 'users' field, then create another field within the model with information about the actual item (for example a url), and then add it to the same User again? That sounds a bit weird.

Comment: You have to instanciate your two models (item and user) and save both instances first before you can bind them with a many to many relation ship. Once they are both saved, you can an item to a user via `my_user_instance.items.add(my_item_instance)`. Or you can do `my_item_instance.users.add(my_user_instance)`. The result will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a model UserItems for each user with a ForeignKey pointing to the user and an item ID pointing to items. The UserItems model should store the unique item IDs of the items that belong to a user. This should scale better if items can be attached to multiple users or if items can exist that aren't attached to any user yet.